# python how to check for open and close tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, tags

i have a XML like file but it is not XML or HTML.

Example of the file:

```
<config-file>
   name myconfig
   date 3-2-2016
</config-file>
  <client>
   <"ABC - CDE & 123">
   </"ABC - CDE & 123">
  </client>
```

We often edit this file and mess up the open or close. Either does not close or even miss place '<' or '>'.
Trying to find a good way to parse the file to make sure it has opens and closes.
I was thinking of:

1-looping thru each line and record if it starts with 
`< + any characters >` and making sure it has a closing 
`</ + any characters>`  and if it does not, it throws an error of the pattern.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Ugh, that sounds very messy. Is it possible for you to modify whatever tool uses this file so it could use real XML or JSON instead?

Comment: That was the initial goal which we could then use any validator out there, but changing this is not possible as many other modules are depending on it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the basics.  You care about three cases only:

1. begin tag
2. end tag
3. everything else (ignore)

Use regular expressions to find the begin & end tags; make sure that the **begin** expression *excludes* a slash as the second character.  Now, make a simple stack: a list of strings will do.  This list will hold the open tags.

Actions:

- begin tag: extract the tag (strip off the angle brackets).  Push it onto the front of the list.
- end tag: extract the tag (strip off the angle brackets and the leading slash).  Check that this tag is the same as the front of the list.  If so, pop it.  If not, issue an error message.  If there's nothing on the list, someone tried to close a tag when there weren't any open; issue a message.
- EOF: when you run out of input, check the list.  Any remaining strings are unclosed tags.  Issue a message.

Note that this also allows you some recovery possibilities.  You can scan the list to see whether an invalid close tag matches something farther down the stack.  This indicates overlapping blocks.  You can look for a close match, suggesting a misspelling.  If you get a close with no possible open, you can issue a message and ignore it.  These steps give you a chance to find multiple errors.

Oh, what the heck ... I've done this enough times ...

```
stack = []

with open("parse_test_1.txt", 'r') as parse_file:
    for line in parse_file:
        print "INPUT LINE:", line
        ltag = line.find('<')
        if ltag > -1:
            rtag = line.find('>')
            if rtag > -1:
                # Found left and right brackets: grab tag
                tag = line[ltag+1: rtag]
                open_tag = tag[0] != '/'
                if open_tag:
                    # Add tag to stack
                    stack.append(tag)
                    print "TRACE open", stack
                else:
                    tag = tag[1:]
                    if len(stack) == 0:
                        print "No blocks are open; tried to close", tag
                    else:
                        if stack[-1] == tag:
                            # Close the block
                            stack.pop()
                            print "TRACE close", tag, stack
                        else:
                            print "Tried to close", tag, "but most recent open block is", stack[0]
                            if tag in stack:
                                stack.remove(tag)
                                print "Prior block closed; continuing"

if len(stack):
    print "Blocks still open at EOF:", stack
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. this is great stuff.