# Check whether the HTML tags in form of the escape sequences are well-formed

Tags: python, xml

I am working with the ALTO-XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#"
      xmlns:page="http://schema.primaresearch.org/PAGE/gts/pagecontent/2013-07-15"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/alto.xsd">
               ... 
                  <String CONTENT="154. &lt;b&gt;Bailly&lt;/b&gt; (Jean-Sylvain), astronome, maire de Paris. L. sig.,"/>
                  <String CONTENT="155. &lt;b&gt;Barbier&lt;/b&gt; (l’abbé H.), auteur de la &lt;i&gt;Biographie du clergé con¬&lt;/i&gt;"/>
                  <String CONTENT="&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;Salle du premier&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;"/>

               ...
</alto>
```

which contains the following escape sequences replacing the HTML tags annotated beforehand:

- `&lt;b&gt;&lt;/b&gt;` instead of `<b></b>`;
- `&lt;i&gt;&lt;/i&gt;` instead of `<i></i>`;

Note that the input file also contains the nested tags:

- `&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;` instead of `<b><i></i></b>`.

I am supposed to verify that the tags in form of the escape sequences are well-formed, so that every open tag has a corresponding closing tag, and if that is not the case, the program needs to indicate the error.

I have tried to adjust [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761395/13449095) code by replacing the angle brackets with their corresponding escape sequences, including the regex for matching the letters `b` and `i`:

```
stack = [] 
import re

with open("1856_10_LAV_N03-2.txt", 'r') as parse_file:
    for line in parse_file:
        print ("INPUT LINE:", line)
        ltag = line.find('&lt;[bi]&gt;')
        if ltag > -1:
            rtag = line.find('&lt;\/[bi]&gt;')
            if rtag > -1:
                # Found left and right brackets: grab tag
                tag = line[ltag: rtag]
                open_tag = tag[0] != '/'
                if open_tag:
                    # Add tag to stack
                    stack.append(tag)
                    print ("TRACE open", stack)
                else:
                    tag = tag[1:]
                    if len(stack) == 0:
                        print ("No blocks are open; tried to close", tag)
                    else:
                        if stack[-1] == tag:
                            # Close the block
                            stack.pop()
                            print ("TRACE close", tag, stack)
                        else:
                            print ("Tried to close", tag, "but most recent open block is", stack[0])
                            if tag in stack:
                                stack.remove(tag)
                                print ("Prior block closed; continuing")

if len(stack):
    print ("Blocks still open at EOF:", stack)
```

However, it only generates the input lines, without any error messages, even when the tags are not well-formed:

```
INPUT LINE: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

INPUT LINE: <alto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

INPUT LINE:       xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#"

INPUT LINE:       xmlns:page="http://schema.primaresearch.org/PAGE/gts/pagecontent/2013-07-15"

INPUT LINE:       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/alto.xsd">

INPUT LINE:                ... 

INPUT LINE:                   <String CONTENT="154. Bailly&lt;/b&gt; (Jean-Sylvain), astronome, maire de Paris. L. sig.,"/> ----------> # it fails to indicate the error for the 'Bailly&lt;/b&gt;'

INPUT LINE:                   <String CONTENT="155. &lt;b&gt;Barbier&lt;/b&gt; (l’abbé H.), auteur de la &lt;i&gt;Biographie du clergé con¬&lt;/i&gt;"/>

INPUT LINE:                   <String CONTENT="&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;Salle du premier&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;"/>

INPUT LINE: 

INPUT LINE:                ...

INPUT LINE: </alto>
```

Any suggestions on how to improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

You've inherited a mess of an XML design.

Here is a sketch of how you might complete your assignment of noting the well-formedness of the reconstituted XML markup currently stored as XML attributes:

1. If the overall XML document is not well-formed as given, apply the techniques given in [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085) to get the overall XML document to be well-formed.
2. Use an XML parser to retrieve each of the attribute values containing escaped XML.  For each such attribute value,

   1. Lexically replace `&lt;` with `<` and `&gt;` with `>`.  This assumes
      that all `&lt;` and `&gt;` are parts of tags for now.
   2. Wrap the reconstituted attribute value in a dummy root element and start a new XML parse of this temporary XML document.
   3. Report any well-formedness errors.
   4. If some of the `&lt;` and `&gt;` were standalone, not parts of tags, then
      again use the techniques given in [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085) to repair.

If at all possible, redesign your XML in the first place not to store markup in attribute values; such a design is fundamentally flawed and leads to problems such as those you're currently experiencing.

Comment: The overall XML document is well-formed, but I included only the relevant part in my example above. I modified my XML file like this: `<root>
   <String CONTENT="154. Bailly</b> (Jean-Sylvain), astronome, ..."/></root>` and run the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761133/python-how-to-check-for-open-and-close-tags/35761395#35761395) code - I expected the `No blocks are open; tried to close Bailly` message, but got, e.g. `TRACE open ['<root', '<String CONTENT="154. Bailly</b']` and `Blocks still open at EOF: ['<root', '<String CONTENT="154. Bailly</b', '</root']`.

Comment: Don't modify the attribute values in your XML like that.    (XML cannot have `<` characters in attribute values.)  Parse the XML and process the targeted attribute values as strings as described in 2.1-4 above.   When I said that the XML design is a mess, I meant that the decision to store escaped markup as XML attributes was a big mistake; markup should be stored as elements, not encoded within attributes.